# Laravel : Eloquent Model::all() returns nothing

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

Books model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Books extends Model{
//
   public $table = 'books';
}
```

My controller function.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Books;

class HomeController extends Controller
  {
          public function addbooks()
          {
           $book = Books::all();
           print_r ($book);
          }
 }
```

So the function **addbooks**, doesn't return anything.
I am using sqlite DB.
Attached is a screenshot of my SQL result.
[image: select result]

php artisan tinker result.

[image]

Comment: In `php artisan tinker`, please do `App\Books::query()->toSql()` and add the output to your question. Also, try `dd($book)` instead of `print_r` - it's possible your `print_r` output just isn't showing up.

Comment: @ceejayoz, I edited my question with ur suggestion pls have a look, and also dd($book) returns null.

Comment: At this point my suspicion is you're accessing a different database. Can you dump `config('database')` and make sure you're accessing the correct SQLite DB?

Comment: I just did that, I am acceding the right DB(only DB on my machine). my result from dump

`"sqlite" ["database"]=> string(67) "/Users/myname/Documents/Laravel/librarian/database/librarian.sqlite"`

Comment: Does `App\Books::all()` in Tinker return null? Are you able to add data via Tinker (`App\Books::create(['author' => 'Foo', 'title' => 'Bar', ...])`) and have that save and show up successfully?

Comment: `App\Books::all()` in tinker returns an object with correct result.

Comment: @ceejayoz - After running this command on tinker it started to work on the browser, weird. Thanks a lot for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's convention is plural table names by default. But when you write a class name (for Model) it should be singular. Try 'Book' as your class name.

Comment: Tried it, Same result `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( ) )`. Does wat you say still applies even when you specify a `$table` inside your model.